# Undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()' error in OpenCV 3.4.3

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I recently installed OpenCV 3.4.3
But some libraries in OpenCV are not running.

This is my example code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
}
```

And this is the comment I entered

> g++ tmp.cpp

And the results came out as follows.

> /tmp/ccsulwjG.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
>   tmp.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to`cv::String::deallocate()'
>   /tmp/ccsulwjG.o: In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
>   tmp.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_[_ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_]+0x28): undefined reference to`cv::String::deallocate()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Then how can I get the exec file in this situation?
My ubuntu version is 14.04

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Then is it only if I fix the header files myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to set dependency, like `-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc`

Comment: Hello, How can I set dependency my code?

Comment: Please see the marked answer. Galians help only help you to find the correct libraries you have to specify.

Comment: You are welcome:)

Comment: How do you set this with Cmake?

Comment: @galian, my Makefile has -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc set already, but it is still giving me this error.