# Building a cmake c++ project that includes opencv librarie

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, mingw, vcpkg

I am building a c++ project with CMake, this project depends on OpenCV library that was installed using Vcpkg.

Here is my `CMakeList.txt` file :

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for CMakeProject2, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
set( CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" )


# Find Package
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

# Additional Include Directories
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

message("hello world " ${OpenCV_LIB_DIR} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

# Additional Library Directories
link_directories( ${OpenCV_LIB_DIR} )
link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS})


#set( OpenCV_DIR "C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/opencv" )
# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeProject2 "CMakeProject2.cpp" "CMakeProject2.h")

# Additional Dependencies
target_link_libraries( CMakeProject2 ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

CMakeProject2.cpp file :

```
#include "CMakeProject2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "OpenCV version : " << CV_VERSION << endl;
    cout << "Hello CMake." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using these commands to build these project :

1. `cmake ..\CMakeProject2 -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`
2. `make`

and this is what i get :

```
\CMakeProject2\build>make
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable CMakeProject2.exe
CMakeFiles\CMakeProject2.dir/objects.a(CMakeProject2.cpp.obj):CMakeProject2.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv6StringD1Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD1Ev]+0x11): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles\CMakeProject2.dir/objects.a(CMakeProject2.cpp.obj):CMakeProject2.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_[_ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_]+0x25): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeProject2.exe] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CMakeProject2.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

Comment: No, OpenCV_LIBS is correct

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491314/undefined-reference-to-cvstringdeallocate-error-in-opencv-3-4-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run those commands :

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake ..
```

and

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, you can not use `-G "MinGW Makefiles"`.

Currently, vcpkg does not offer support for MinGW.

It was [requested](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/3752), but eventually it has [not been implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/4418) and the concluding comment from the vcpkg maintainers consists of this suggestion for anyone who would like to pick the MinGW support again:

> However, we have not looked much into using mingw so far. If you have
>   a functioning CMake toolchain file, you can follow our triplet
>   documentation[1] to create a `triplets/x64-windows-mingw.cmake` file
>   that will use that toolchain to build libraries.
>
> [1] https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md