# If I already have opencv python, do I need to install opencv C++ to build C++ code, or do I need to set dependencies?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I've already been having opencv python on my system for quite some time now for I work predominantly in python3. Now, however, I have been trying to run a repo written in C++ which uses opencv C++.

I didn't install opencv C++ because I thought that opencv python is just a wrapper around opencv C++, so it must be having the code needed to run opencv C++ anyway.

Upon running `make`,though, I get errors such as `undefined reference to 'cv::String::deallocate()'`

I am looking at other links such as [Undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()' error in OpenCV 3.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491314/undefined-reference-to-cvstringdeallocate-error-in-opencv-3-4-3) and [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), but that's confusing me a bit more. How do I go about setting the dependency mentioned in the 1st link?

**EDIT**: Following this the last part of the output of the make command, which is were I get errors:

[image]

The part of my `Makefile` handling opencv has the `OPENCV_CFLAGS` and `OPENCV_LIBS` flags. Here is a part of the `Makefile`:-

```
# Makefile.in generated by automake 1.15.1 from Makefile.am.
# Makefile.  Generated from Makefile.in by configure.

# Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

# This Makefile.in is free software; the Free Software Foundation
# gives unlimited permission to copy and/or distribute it,
# with or without modifications, as long as this notice is preserved.

# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law; without
# even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
# PARTICULAR PURPOSE.



am__is_gnu_make = { \
  if test -z '$(MAKELEVEL)'; then \
    false; \
  elif test -n '$(MAKE_HOST)'; then \
    true; \
  elif test -n '$(MAKE_VERSION)' && test -n '$(CURDIR)'; then \
    true; \
  else \
    false; \
  fi; \
}
am__make_running_with_option = \
  case $${target_option-} in \
      ?) ;; \
      *) echo "am__make_running_with_option: internal error: invalid" \
              "target option '$${target_option-}' specified" >&2; \
         exit 1;; \
  esac; \
  has_opt=no; \
  sane_makeflags=$$MAKEFLAGS; \
  if $(am__is_gnu_make); then \
    sane_makeflags=$$MFLAGS; \
  else \
    case $$MAKEFLAGS in \
      *\\[\ \   ]*) \
        bs=\\; \
        sane_makeflags=`printf '%s\n' "$$MAKEFLAGS" \
          | sed "s/$$bs$$bs[$$bs $$bs   ]*//g"`;; \
    esac; \
  fi; \
  skip_next=no; \
  strip_trailopt () \
  { \
    flg=`printf '%s\n' "$$flg" | sed "s/$$1.*$$//"`; \
  }; \
  for flg in $$sane_makeflags; do \
    test $$skip_next = yes && { skip_next=no; continue; }; \
    case $$flg in \
      *=*|--*) continue;; \
        -*I) strip_trailopt 'I'; skip_next=yes;; \
      -*I?*) strip_trailopt 'I';; \
        -*O) strip_trailopt 'O'; skip_next=yes;; \
      -*O?*) strip_trailopt 'O';; \
        -*l) strip_trailopt 'l'; skip_next=yes;; \
      -*l?*) strip_trailopt 'l';; \
      -[dEDm]) skip_next=yes;; \
      -[JT]) skip_next=yes;; \
    esac; \
    case $$flg in \
      *$$target_option*) has_opt=yes; break;; \
    esac; \
  done; \
  test $$has_opt = yes
am__make_dryrun = (target_option=n; $(am__make_running_with_option))
am__make_keepgoing = (target_option=k; $(am__make_running_with_option))
pkgdatadir = $(datadir)/libxcam
pkgincludedir = $(includedir)/libxcam
pkglibdir = $(libdir)/libxcam
pkglibexecdir = $(libexecdir)/libxcam
am__cd = CDPATH="$${ZSH_VERSION+.}$(PATH_SEPARATOR)" && cd
install_sh_DATA = $(install_sh) -c -m 644
install_sh_PROGRAM = $(install_sh) -c
install_sh_SCRIPT = $(install_sh) -c
INSTALL_HEADER = $(INSTALL_DATA)
transform = $(program_transform_name)
NORMAL_INSTALL = :
PRE_INSTALL = :
POST_INSTALL = :
NORMAL_UNINSTALL = :
PRE_UNINSTALL = :
POST_UNINSTALL = :
build_triplet = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
host_triplet = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
subdir = .
ACLOCAL_M4 = $(top_srcdir)/aclocal.m4
am__aclocal_m4_deps = $(top_srcdir)/m4/libtool.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/ltoptions.m4 $(top_srcdir)/m4/ltsugar.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/ltversion.m4 $(top_srcdir)/m4/lt~obsolete.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/xcam-utils.m4 $(top_srcdir)/configure.ac
am__configure_deps = $(am__aclocal_m4_deps) $(CONFIGURE_DEPENDENCIES) \
    $(ACLOCAL_M4)
DIST_COMMON = $(srcdir)/Makefile.am $(top_srcdir)/configure \
    $(am__configure_deps) $(am__DIST_COMMON)
am__CONFIG_DISTCLEAN_FILES = config.status config.cache config.log \
 configure.lineno config.status.lineno
mkinstalldirs = $(install_sh) -d
CONFIG_HEADER = config.h
CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES =
CONFIG_CLEAN_VPATH_FILES =
AM_V_P = $(am__v_P_$(V))
am__v_P_ = $(am__v_P_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_P_0 = false
am__v_P_1 = :
AM_V_GEN = $(am__v_GEN_$(V))
am__v_GEN_ = $(am__v_GEN_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_GEN_0 = @echo "  GEN     " $@;
am__v_GEN_1 = 
AM_V_at = $(am__v_at_$(V))
am__v_at_ = $(am__v_at_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_at_0 = @
am__v_at_1 = 
SOURCES =
DIST_SOURCES =
RECURSIVE_TARGETS = all-recursive check-recursive cscopelist-recursive \
    ctags-recursive dvi-recursive html-recursive info-recursive \
    install-data-recursive install-dvi-recursive \
    install-exec-recursive install-html-recursive \
    install-info-recursive install-pdf-recursive \
    install-ps-recursive install-recursive installcheck-recursive \
    installdirs-recursive pdf-recursive ps-recursive \
    tags-recursive uninstall-recursive
am__can_run_installinfo = \
  case $$AM_UPDATE_INFO_DIR in \
    n|no|NO) false;; \
    *) (install-info --version) >/dev/null 2>&1;; \
  esac
RECURSIVE_CLEAN_TARGETS = mostlyclean-recursive clean-recursive \
  distclean-recursive maintainer-clean-recursive
am__recursive_targets = \
  $(RECURSIVE_TARGETS) \
  $(RECURSIVE_CLEAN_TARGETS) \
  $(am__extra_recursive_targets)
AM_RECURSIVE_TARGETS = $(am__recursive_targets:-recursive=) TAGS CTAGS \
    cscope distdir dist dist-all distcheck
am__tagged_files = $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES) $(TAGS_FILES) \
    $(LISP)config.h.in
# Read a list of newline-separated strings from the standard input,
# and print each of them once, without duplicates.  Input order is
# *not* preserved.
am__uniquify_input = $(AWK) '\
  BEGIN { nonempty = 0; } \
  { items[$$0] = 1; nonempty = 1; } \
  END { if (nonempty) { for (i in items) print i; }; } \
'
# Make sure the list of sources is unique.  This is necessary because,
# e.g., the same source file might be shared among _SOURCES variables
# for different programs/libraries.
am__define_uniq_tagged_files = \
  list='$(am__tagged_files)'; \
  unique=`for i in $$list; do \
    if test -f "$$i"; then echo $$i; else echo $(srcdir)/$$i; fi; \
  done | $(am__uniquify_input)`
ETAGS = etags
CTAGS = ctags
CSCOPE = cscope
DIST_SUBDIRS = xcore shaders modules plugins wrapper capi tests \
    pkgconfig
am__DIST_COMMON = $(srcdir)/Makefile.in $(srcdir)/config.h.in AUTHORS \
    COPYING ChangeLog NEWS compile config.guess config.sub \
    install-sh ltmain.sh missing
DISTFILES = $(DIST_COMMON) $(DIST_SOURCES) $(TEXINFOS) $(EXTRA_DIST)
distdir = $(PACKAGE)-$(VERSION)
top_distdir = $(distdir)
am__remove_distdir = \
  if test -d "$(distdir)"; then \
    find "$(distdir)" -type d ! -perm -200 -exec chmod u+w {} ';' \
      && rm -rf "$(distdir)" \
      || { sleep 5 && rm -rf "$(distdir)"; }; \
  else :; fi
am__post_remove_distdir = $(am__remove_distdir)
am__relativize = \
  dir0=`pwd`; \
  sed_first='s,^\([^/]*\)/.*$$,\1,'; \
  sed_rest='s,^[^/]*/*,,'; \
  sed_last='s,^.*/\([^/]*\)$$,\1,'; \
  sed_butlast='s,/*[^/]*$$,,'; \
  while test -n "$$dir1"; do \
    first=`echo "$$dir1" | sed -e "$$sed_first"`; \
    if test "$$first" != "."; then \
      if test "$$first" = ".."; then \
        dir2=`echo "$$dir0" | sed -e "$$sed_last"`/"$$dir2"; \
        dir0=`echo "$$dir0" | sed -e "$$sed_butlast"`; \
      else \
        first2=`echo "$$dir2" | sed -e "$$sed_first"`; \
        if test "$$first2" = "$$first"; then \
          dir2=`echo "$$dir2" | sed -e "$$sed_rest"`; \
        else \
          dir2="../$$dir2"; \
        fi; \
        dir0="$$dir0"/"$$first"; \
      fi; \
    fi; \
    dir1=`echo "$$dir1" | sed -e "$$sed_rest"`; \
  done; \
  reldir="$$dir2"
DIST_ARCHIVES = $(distdir).tar.gz
GZIP_ENV = --best
DIST_TARGETS = dist-gzip
distuninstallcheck_listfiles = find . -type f -print
am__distuninstallcheck_listfiles = $(distuninstallcheck_listfiles) \
  | sed 's|^\./|$(prefix)/|' | grep -v '$(infodir)/dir$$'
distcleancheck_listfiles = find . -type f -print
ACLOCAL = ${SHELL} /media/ubuntu/apps1/mvision/tech/SVS3D/libxcam_test/missing aclocal-1.15
AMTAR = $${TAR-tar}
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY = 1
AR = ar
AUTOCONF = ${SHELL} /media/ubuntu/apps1/mvision/tech/SVS3D/libxcam_test/missing autoconf
AUTOHEADER = ${SHELL} /media/ubuntu/apps1/mvision/tech/SVS3D/libxcam_test/missing autoheader
AUTOMAKE = ${SHELL} /media/ubuntu/apps1/mvision/tech/SVS3D/libxcam_test/missing automake-1.15
AWK = gawk
CC = gcc
CCDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CFLAGS = -g -O2
CPP = gcc -E
CPPFLAGS = 
CXX = g++
CXXCPP = g++ -E
CXXDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
CYGPATH_W = echo
DEFS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DEPDIR = .deps
DLLTOOL = false
DOXYGEN = 
DSYMUTIL = 
DUMPBIN = 
ECHO_C = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_T = 
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
EXEEXT = 
FGREP = /bin/grep -F
GAWK = gawk
GREP = /bin/grep
GST_ALLOCATOR_CFLAGS = -pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
GST_ALLOCATOR_LIBS = -lgstallocators-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
GST_CFLAGS = -pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
GST_LIBS = -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
GST_VIDEO_CFLAGS = -pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/orc-0.4 -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
GST_VIDEO_LIBS = -lgstvideo-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
IA_AIQ_CFLAGS = 
IA_AIQ_LIBS = 
IA_IMAGING_CFLAGS = 
IA_IMAGING_LIBS = 
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_DATA = ${INSTALL} -m 644
INSTALL_PROGRAM = ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_SCRIPT = ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM = $(install_sh) -c -s
LD = /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
LDFLAGS = 
LIBCL_CFLAGS = 
LIBCL_LIBS = -lOpenCL
LIBDRM_CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/libdrm
LIBDRM_LIBS = -ldrm
LIBGBM_CFLAGS = 
LIBGBM_LIBS = 
LIBGL_CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/libdrm
LIBGL_LIBS = -lGL
LIBOBJS = 
LIBOSG_CFLAGS = 
LIBOSG_LIBS = 
LIBS = 
LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool
LIBVULKAN_CFLAGS = 
LIBVULKAN_LIBS = 
LIPO = 
LN_S = ln -s
LTLIBOBJS = 
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH = 
MAKEINFO = ${SHELL} /media/ubuntu/apps1/mvision/tech/SVS3D/libxcam_test/missing makeinfo
MANIFEST_TOOL = :
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
NM = /usr/bin/nm -B
NMEDIT = 
OBJDUMP = objdump
OBJEXT = o
OPENCV_CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/opencv4
OPENCV_LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudafeatures2d -lopencv_cudaobjdetect -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_cudaoptflow -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_cudalegacy -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_cudawarping -lopencv_wechat_qrcode -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_cudaimgproc -lopencv_cudafilters -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_core -lopencv_cudev
```

P.S.: I have found that allocate() and deallocate() have been declared in cvstd.hpp and I see definitions for them in the same file. But I'm not sure why the linker can't find it.

Also, my Makefile has dependencies such as `-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc` are already set. I don't why I'm still getting a link error.

P.P.S.: I am new to C++, so much of the code compilation process is unfamiliar to me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your `Makefile` might be of interest. There might be missing arguments for the libraries like described in your first link.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, so I don't need to install opencv c++, right?

Comment: You're probably new to C++. The title mentions **run** C++ code, but the error is a **build** error.

Comment: My first guess was that you are missing the devel. package for OpenCV. However, in this case I would've expected _compile_ errors but you got a _link_ error. Hence, the headers could be found (which I would expect to be part of the devel. package). You could check on your side whether the devel. package for OpenCV is there. You also could [edit] your question to include the `Makefile` or at least how you link your application to expose whether all needed library settings are there.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, thanks for the reply. I could not include the entire Makefile because it exceeded the character count of 30000, but have posted a little part of it. I'm not sure if this part consists of the lines that link the application, though. Any help?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, I think allocate() and deallocate() have been declared in cvstd.hpp and I see definitions for them in the same file. But I'm not sure why the linker can't find it.

Comment: Which version of OpenCV do you intend to use? Recent versions seem to be 4.x. In the past, I read about OpenCV 3.x. In you snapshot (:-( should've been text), I saw `/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp` - the header where `cv::String` is defined in. Maybe, it's in fact an issue of the missing devel. package for the intended version of OpenCV, and the build somehow grabbed an old API instead which would be an explanation for the link errors...

Comment: In C++, there is nothing which stops you to compile against one set of headers and linking with an unrelated library but it may for sure result in such link issues. The linker is not able to check whether the linked objects match the declarations which were used for compiling - it just tries to fiddle the symbols together.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, I'm sorry if this sounds confusing, but my include directory has the path /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2 (opencv2 contained in a folder called opencv4), but my /usr/local/lib folder contains opencv4 only and other .so files related to opencv4.

Comment: According to the error message, `/usr/include/opencv2` has been used. Either this is a link to `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2`, or the compiler didn't use the header you intended. I believe you have to sort this out because it supports my suspicion that you compile against one version and link against another. And you still didn't answer _which_ version you _intend_ to use...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, Ahh, I got it. It was an issue with my folder paths. Thanks for stepping through this with me, really pointed me in the right direction. Btw, I have Opencv 4.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the error. Thanks @Scheff'sCat for the comments. The only version of opencv that I have on my system is opencv 4.5.2.

I'm not sure how helpful my answer will be to everybody because the problem was more system specific. I use a communal Desktop at work, and the folder structure is a bit strange based on how other users have installed packages and moved folders around.

`/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2` contains all the files needed by the repo I'm trying to build. But the make command accesses `/usr/include/opencv2` which doesn't contain few of the files needed by the repo. I just had to move the contents of `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2` to `/usr/include/opencv2` and the `make` worked.

Answer (score 2):

To build and run C++ code that uses OpenCV C++, you need to install the OpenCV C++ library and set up dependencies. While OpenCV Python is a wrapper around the C++ library, it doesn't include the necessary dependencies for C++ code. Therefore, installing OpenCV Python alone won't work.

If you encounter errors during the build process, such as "undefined reference to 'cv::String::deallocate()'", it indicates a linking issue with the OpenCV C++ library. To resolve this issue, you need to link the library correctly to your C++ project during the build process.

In summary, to build and run C++ code that uses OpenCV C++, you need to install the OpenCV C++ library and correctly set up dependencies. OpenCV Python isn't sufficient for building C++ code, so it's important to follow the correct installation and setup steps to avoid errors.